# Expected identifier or '(' error on private instance variables

Tags: objective-c, interface, cocos2d-iphone

I'm using Cocos2D for the first time and trying to set up my initial scene. I just followed this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/15267/how-to-make-a-platform-game-like-super-mario-brothers-part-2 and got it working perfectly. I even copied the code for the GameLayer over to use as a template for my Level0, changing the appropriate value to fit.

I'm getting an error in my private interface `Expected identifier of '(' before '{' token

```
#import "Level0.h"

#import "Player.h"

@interface Level0 ()
{     /// this is where I'm getting the error
    CCTMXTiledMap* map;

    Player* player;

    CCTMXLayer* walls;
    CCTMXLayer* portalWalls;

    BOOL gameOver;
}

@end


@implementation Level0
....
```

I've coded private interfaces a million times and it even looks identical to the tutorial project. Does anyone know of reasons why this would flag an error?

Comment: The problem is actually in one of those header files.

Answer (score 1):

The bad syntax is actually in one of those header files. You may be able to track it down by compiling the troublesome header itself rather than just including it. Comment out the `#include`s, then in Xcode's file inspector change the "File Type" from "Default - C header" to "Objective-C" source:

[image]
[image]

and add it to your target as a member:

[image]

Then compile. You might get some linker errors too, but you should also get this same "Expected identifier" error, now pointing somewhere near the actual site of the problem.

Don't forget to switch those settings back afterwards.